# Make multiple firestore queries in a cloud function to avoid multiple RTTs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### Introduction

In my use case, I have a screen that renders 8 lists of items. Each list, make a different query to Firestore asynchronously (as they need documents from different collections...). I have profiled the execution time of those 8 queries, and in total (the time I wait for getting all the data from those 8 queries), I get from 3 to 6 secs:

> execution time: 5539.793ms

For each query, I am retrieving around 30 documents. Here is how they look in general:

```
const query = playersRef
    .where("random", ">=", randomId)
    .where("level", "==", currentUserLevel)
    .where("location.country", "==", currentUserCountry)
    .orderBy("random")
    .limit(30);
```

### Question

I am a little confused. I know that making 8 requests will result in 8 RTTs, but I don't know if the most part of this time is caused by the distance to the data center, or by the queries themselves without taking into account this distance (from Spain to Iowa).

Could the fact of implementing all these queries in a single Cloud Function (hosted in Iowa, and which returns everything at once) reduce the execution time considerably?

Thank you.

Comment: This seems like something you could benchmark for yourself to get a definitive answer, for your specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say and I agree with what Doug said in the comments that the best way you could get a meaninful answer to this is by benchmarking it yourself, however, I am writing this answer for some thing you should take into consideration:

- **Latency due to physical distance between your app, the cloud function and your firestore**: generally speaking the  smaller the distance the faster your app, this is true in the paths `you -> cloud function` and `cloud function -> cloud firestore`, I would recommend that you use the region `europe-west2(London)` since it is a region near you that offer both firestore and cloud function, the latter at tier 1 pricing. Also I have found this [site](http://www.gcping.com/) that measures the ping between you and the regions in GCP, not official, but potencially useful.
- **Async calls to firestore (If you are not using it already)**: Use Async calls on each query, if you keep using a single function, that way you won't have to wait for each query to complete before starting the next one, optimizing the time your function takes to fetch all documents.
- **Use the performance tips of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) to improve the performance of your code**.

Comment: Yeah, I making async calls to firestore in my code. I have moved all those reads (around 180 document reads in queries of  25 documents aprox.) The result has been around 0.5 (sometimes 1) secs less. The cons are a somewhat unreadable code and making an extra call to GCF (because we do not consult directly from the client). But pretty good the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

seems that batched writes or transactions can help  you in this issue...
Link:[firebase docs about batch writes and transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)